# Why are some executive producers credited individually?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, credits, daredevil-tv

I am watching Netflix *Daredevil* (2nd Season) and I noticed that whereas some executive producers appear collectively (Stan Lee among then), others are credited *individually*. Is there some reason for this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Same reason everything else about their credits is formatted as it is: their contracts said so.

In the specific case of EPs, there's really three different "kinds" of executive producer for a TV show (with movies it's slightly different):

- Some executive producers are credited because they own the rights to intellectual property that requires they be given such credit. Stan Lee is one example; another is Siegel and Shuster being given EP credit anytime someone uses Superman.
- Some executive producers are financial supporters only. They pony up the money needed to make a production, in exchange for a cut of the profits.
- Some executive producers are hands-on, managing the production and given direction to the content. (This is *mostly* a TV phenomenon -- executive producers on movies are rarely this directly involved)

Depending on how involved a given EP is, or what they did to get EP credit, will dictate how they get credited. Typically, producers that are hands-on with a given episode will be given "more" credit that someone who was involved at a higher level; people who's EP credit comes attached to some IP might specify that they need to be credited a specific way (perhaps as "creators" in addition to EP).

Ultimately, it all comes down to finances and legalities and giving everyone what they were promised.

Comment: I'll upvote you, but I want producer credit first.

Comment: One movie exception is when one of the actors/directors is also financing (but not organising) the production. Then they're a pretty directly involved EP.